# What is the complement of this Context-Free Language?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

$L =  \{ a^i b^i c^i | i \ge 0 \}$

I understand that it's everything not in $L$, so every string where $\#a's = \#b's = \#c's$ is not in $L$ complement. However, I wasn't sure if strings such as $ba$ or $cba$ would be in the complement.

Comment: The complement consists of all words not in the language.

Comment: Yes, "everything except $L$" means all the possible words (i.e., $\{a,b,c\}^*$) except those that are in $L$.

Comment: The language is one of the classic examples of non-context free languages.